# square squares with diagonals also squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, latin-square

The numbers reading across and down in these squares are square:
$\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 4 & 4\\
4 &8&4\\
4&4&1
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{ccc}
5&2&9\\
2&5&6\\
9&6&1
\end{array}$

$\begin{array}{cccc}
2&1&1&6\\
1&2&2&5\\
1&2&9&6\\
6&5&6&1
\end{array}$

Are there any such square squares where the diagonals are also squares? If not in base 10, is it possible in other bases?

Comment: Since you allow repeated numbers, the k times k square with only k's is a solution. Do you have a restriction in mind?

Comment: Not every digit is the same, and there are no leading 0s.

Comment: @Phira: But none of 22, 333, 4444,..., 999999999 is a square! Have I misunderstood you?

Comment: @TonyK I have misunderstood the question because in the first example, the sums are also squares.

Comment: There are no 3x3 matrices that do what you want in base 10 :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those matrices are certainly hard to find, I tried it a lot and found that there are no $4\times4$ or $3\times3$ matrices that do what you want in base $10$ or below. However watch this one in base $11$:

$$\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 9 & 5\\
9 & 6 & 1\\
5 & 1 & 9
\end{array}$$

You have

$169_{11}=196=14^2$

$195_{11}=225=15^2$

$519_{11}=625=25^2$

$565_{11}=676=26^2$

$961_{11}=1156=34^2$

All colums, rows, diagonals when read in any way (colums and rows only down and right) are squares, woha ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Uuuuh yes, take any n^2xn^2 matrix with the same number everywhere.

Wait, take any $n^2Xn^2$ matrix, and put any of your matrices in each spot.